# SQL Recursion desc select

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following SQL Recursion in mariaDB

```
with recursive supervisor as (
select * from staff where staff_id=6
union
select s.* from staff as s, supervisor as su
where s.staff_id=su.supervisor_id
)
select * from supervisor;
```

This is the execution result

[image]

How can i change the order into descending.

Comment: descending what?

Comment: so the staffs highest supervisor comes. at the moment mac diver is the first in the result but he is the lowest staff member.

Comment: `ORDER BY columnname DESC`

Comment: yeah i know... but i have no column i can order by.

Comment: i just found a similar problem that tells me their is no solution exept adding an index maybe in the recursion block https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779180/reverse-the-natural-order-of-a-mysql-table-without-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `ROWNUM` as you got through, then `ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC` on the outer `SELECT`.